# What is a logical flaw of my proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

I know the following statement is false: A semigroup with left identity and right inverse is group. I have a counterexample. But I somehow unable to see problem in my proof that stating the statement is true.

My proof goes follow:
Let $G$ be a semigroup. Then we know $G$ is a group if and only if it has a left identity and left inverse. We claim a semigroup with left identity and right inverse has also left inverse.

Suppose $g\in G$ and let $g^{-1}$ be a right inverse of $g$. Then
\begin{equation*}
(g^{-1}g)(g^{-1}g)=g^{-1}(gg^{-1})g=g^{-1}g.
\end{equation*}
Therefore $g^{-1}g=e$. Hence $g^{-1}$ is also a left inverse and we can apply the fact that if $G$ has a left identity and left inverse then it is a group. What is wrong with my proof?

Comment: How do you get from $(g^{-1}g)(g^{-1}g)=g^{-1}g$ (which is correct) to $g^{-1}g=e$?

Comment: A semigroup with a left identity may have many left identities. I presume then you have one designated left identity $e$ and right inverse means that for all $a$ there is $b$ with $ab=e$. If $a^2=a$ then $a^2b=ab$, that is $ae=e$. That may not be the same as $a=e$.

Comment: In general, if you have both a proof and a counterexample for some statement, then just work carefully through the proof but using the counterexample in place of the group. That way you should find the point where they disagree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have
$$(g^{-1}g)(g^{-1}g)=g^{-1}g,$$
you immediately go from this to
$$g^{-1}g=e.$$
I'm guessing your logic is to multiply by the right inverse $(g^{-1}g)^{-1}$ on the right hand side. Unfortunately, the right and left identities may not coincide in a semigroup, in other words you actually have
$$(g^{-1}g)e=e.$$
But because $e$ is a left identity, and not a right identity, you cannot get from this to
$$g^{-1}g=e.$$